# AWS EC2 Launch Instance keeps on Failing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am new to AWS EC2 and I wanted to create a sample Server to play around but launching keeps on failing and I can't figure out why.. is there anyone who can help? I am trying to launch the Amazon Linux AMI 2017.09.1 (HVM), SSD Volume Type Machine and t2.micro as the instance type.  Below is the link to the screenshot of the launch status. Thank you.

Screenshot of Launch Status:
[image: Screenshot of Launch Status]

Comment: is it your first ec2 instance?

Comment: yes it is my first ec2 instance

Comment: Also facing the same

Comment: I had requested the supports team to increase my limit, and they told me that I already had enough limits so basically they had done nothing but it worked when I tried again the other day. They told me that it maybe caused because of where (region) I'm accessing the EC2.

Comment: Use different ami leave all the attributes with default value